# Cassandra latency patterns under constant load

Tags: cassandra, performance

I've got pretty unusual latency patterns in my production setup:

the whole cluster (3 machines: 48 gig ram, 7500 rpm disk, 6 cores) shows latency spikes every 10 minutes, all machines at the same time.

See [this screenshot](https://skitch.com/tobsch/eupt4/datastax-opscenter).
I checked the logfiles and it seems as there are no compactions taking place at that time.

I've got 2k reads and 5k reads/sec. No optimizations have been made so far.
Caching is set to "ALL", hit rate for row cache is at ~0,7.

Any ideas? Is tuning memtable size an option?

Best,

Tobias

Comment: *"All machines at the same time"* suggests that the cause is external, i.e. other processes on those machines, or something affecting the network every 10 minutes... unless you are replicating to all 3 machines, and there is some extreme read/write load every 10 minutes?

Comment: I can't imagine which other process could cause this.
Adding more nodes solved it so far. The Servers are all replicated. Strange.

Comment: There are no excessive reads/writes in that time either.